# VBA Word - Find a portion of a word, extend the selection and replace new selection with a new word at the same time

Tags: vba, replace, ms-word

I want to write a sub routine to find all occurrences of a substring, then extend the selection with specified number of characters and replace this new text in all of document body at once. Is it possible?

```
doc.Range.Find.Execute findtext:="T04-WPA-"
Selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=6, Extend:=wdExtend
'(Replacing procedure)
```

Comment: Yes it is possible. It is also likely that you can achieve it without code by using wildcards. If you don't know how to use wildcards with Find see https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/General/UsingWildcards.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't even need VBA for this! All you need is a *wildcard* Find/Replace where:

```
Find = T04-WPA-??????
Replace = new string
```

even an ordinary Find/Replace where:

```
Find = T04-WPA-^?^?^?^?^?^?
Replace = new string
```